# django - what is the most commonly accepted way of including a form within another template?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have been having the hardest time understanding something about django forms (django 1.6), that I thought would have been very easy.

My `home.html` extends my `base.html`.  I also have a `ContactForm()` model that has a view and a template (template is named `contact.html`)

Here is what I want to do.  I want to be able to bring the `contact.html` template into the `home.html` template.  The problem is that when I use {% include %} I lose all my context variables.

What is the correct way of approaching this problem?  I suspect that despite how many times I read and re-read tutorials I am missing something fundamental.

If your answer is that my entire approach is all wrong and you tell me what I should be doing --- I'll accept that too.

Here is the not-working code I currently have:

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    sender = forms.EmailField()
```

views.py:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']

            send_mail(subject, message, sender)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('frontpage/thanks/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    return render(request, 'frontpage/contact.html', 
        {'form': form,})
```

home.html:

```
{% extends 'frontpage/base.html' %}

<!-- lots of markup and template stuff -->    

{% block content %} 

{% include 'frontpage/contact.html' %}

<!-- lots of markup and template stuff -->

{% endblock %}
```

contact.html:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{% include %}` tag doesn't mean "include this view + template"; it means "include the template itself, *just as if you copied and pasted the template text directly into here, nothing more and nothing less.*"

Therefore, it's not using your contact view at all.

Do you need the contact view to be a separate view? (i.e., will you use this as an independent page ever?) If not, I'd put the logic of your view into whatever view drives your homepage.

If you do need a separate contact view *and* to get this on your homepage, I'd try to factor out the form-handling stuff so that you can call it from both the homepage view and the independent contact view. I think that kind of thing is often easier with Class-Based Views, myself. If factoring it out is too difficult for you, you could just copy and paste this same stuff into the home page--that violates the principle of "Don't repeat yourself", but it's a short amount of pretty straightforward code; this might be the lesser of two evils if the alternative is confusing for you.

Good luck!

Comment: i'd like to learn how to do it 'the right way' - so it sounds like i should figure out how to factor out the form handling stuff as you say.

Comment: A good start would be learn the basics of ClassBasedViews. Then you can make a mixin class that has just the handling for your form. You could then have a homepage and contact view that include that in their subclasses.